# How to put multiple edge animate compositions?

Tags: javascript, css, adobe-edge

I have a problem with multiple adobe edge compositions. I would like to put about 5 compositions on a website and assign each of them to a separate buttons so the right composition would be played after pressing the right button.

i didn't have any luck with it so far :/ any help would be much appriciated

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the official documentation under the "Multiple Compositions in a Page":

http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/edgeanimate/api/current/index.html

"The Edge Runtime supports multiple compositions in a single HTML page, but as of Edge Animate 2.0, opening a page with more than one composition in Animate is not supported."

Check your version of edge animate to see if its below 2.0. If so, there is an official post from adobe on how to integrate multiple compositions

http://blogs.adobe.com/edge/2012/05/15/bootstrapping-edge-compositions/